# why learn bash if you know C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix

My objective here is to learn C for a course in systems programming (taught in Linux/UNIX, not Windows).

Oftentimes it's clear that typing commands or a scripting a batch of them together (e.g. for a toolchain) is going to take less time than writing a new C program.

Bash has advantage of convenience, but learning all the bash tricks and syntax has its own learning curve. 
For example, just to do some rudimentary file operations I had to ask this question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63632/find-greatest-last-modified-files-of-dira-file-dirb-file

Wouldn't a student get more out of just learning how `stat` works and write a program to do any loop or `if` constructs?

What are the arguments for learning bash, when you could instead program anything in C e.g. with Linux syscalls like `execve`?

Comment: In many cases bash _isn't_ the best tool for the job, but in many cases it's darn Good Enough, especially for 1-off pieces of code.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, although I don't exactly know what "genuine sysadmin work" is. Maybe all the alternatives to bash syntax for sysadmins suck...idk.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/unix-koans/ten-thousand.html

Answer (score 4):

Sure, but how long is it going to take to code `grep` using your bare hands (i.e. C)?